# I would like to get value from promise value and then return for canActive boolean

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have tried to value from values for using router guard with the path

I tried to use to get values from a promise into `canActivate()` for router guard.

```
private routeURL = new Subject<string> ();

canActivate() {
    if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
        this.getNavigationEnd().then(res => console.log('2 ' + res) );
// I want to get this.getNavigationEnd()'s result[true or false] for router guard's canActivate().

        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/401']);
    return false;
  }

  async getNavigationEnd() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((result) => {
      let value: any;
      value = result;
      this.routeURL.next(value.url);
    });
    const valueArray = this.routeURL.asObservable();
    let bool = false;
    await valueArray.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      if (this.menuURIarray.includes(value)) {
        bool = true;
      } else {
        bool = false;
      }
    });
    console.log('1 ' + bool);
    return bool;
  }
```

If it is possible to get from promise with value, the router guard can check path with router paths.

`this.menuURIarray` is the menu list array. and it compares with the router's navigationEnd path.

And then if it is not the same with this array and navigationEnd, it returns true or false.

Then canActivate uses that for checking. this is my scenario for router guard

Comment: Waiting for the end of a navigation in a guard, which is precisely there to decide if navigation can be done or not, doesn't make much sense. Forget the code for a moment, and explain precisely what your guard should do, in functional terms.

Comment: @JB Nizet The navigationEnd is the user's click which is the same with routerlink in the menu. and this.menuURIarray keeps the visible menu uri values of array then if user types the url which is not included in the array, it should be blocked by router guard

Answer (score 0):

`canActivate` can return both `boolean`, `Promise<boolean>`, `Observable<boolean>`. In your case `canActivate` can just return an **Observable** or **Promise**.

This example filter **NavigationEnd** and return `true`.

```
canActivate() {
    return this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map((event: NavigationEnd) => true),
    )
  }
```

Document: [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: But a guard is precisely used to decide if the navigation can be done or not, so waiting for the navigation end in a guard doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You're right. So in this case it should be `NavigationStart` right?

Comment: No. the guard causes the router not to to anything until it returns true or false. Listening to reouter events in a guard doesn't make much sense. The OP should explain what he/she's trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for writing. it doesn't work at all. just stuck and also it doesn't work commands in this.router.events.pipe's map...